# JQuery/Zepro $.ajax request always fails in Firefox/Chrome works in Safari

Tags: json, jquery

I've just started trying to convert my first and still in development Webapp into a mobile app with Phonegap. I'm very confused with going from Server side page generation to client side page generation so I'm starting to do some basic stuff as test stubs, so I'll actually be able to get started writing my apps.

I'm trying to do an AJAX post with data to a Ruby Sinatra web service and receive a response in the browser. I can't get Firefox or Chrome to ever take the success path.

This is just testing right now, so it doesn't do anything useful or logical. The Sinatra route looks like this:

```
post "/auth/check" do
    status 200
    content_type :json
        { :login => true }.to_json
end
```

The html/javascript looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <!-- <script src="js/lib/zepto.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"</script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"</script>
        <script>
        var BASEURL = "http://localhost:4567";
        function login(){   
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: BASEURL + '/auth/check',
                type: "POST",
                data: { email: 'somedude@example.com',
                        password: 'e'
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr, type){
                    alert('Y U NO WORK?')
                }
            });
        }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onClick="login()">Click Me</input"
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't get Firefox or Chrome to do anything other than give the "Y U NO WORK?" alert. Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried switching from Zepto.js to JQuery/JQuery mobile, I've tried changing the data type to jsonp, using curl I've confirmed that the Sinatra route is returning something and a 200 status code which is what JQuery should be checking for.

Comment: It seems the ports are different in each case. This is sufficient to make the target URL a different origin. Look up "same origin policy" and "cross-origin resource sharing"

Comment: Thanks for your help Jan, I looked further into the cross origin thing and got Sinatra to work by adding a gem for jsonp. The issue is now that the javascript is always creating a http get and never a post, I've tried both type: "POST" and method: "POST" but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: You can't send a POST request via JSONP. Look into how JSONP works.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I guess I'll have to modify my project to just work with GET, shouldn't be too big a deal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, based on help by Jan Dvorak, firstly I needed Sinatra to actually return JSONP data. Add a GEM for JSONP support:

```
require 'sinatra/jsonp'
```

Secondly the route can only be a HTTP GET, use the JSONP function to return something:

```
get "/auth/check/" do
  content_type :json
  status 200
  @data = true
  JSONP @data
end
```